# Is there a simple way to copy all text in PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, psd

Is there a simple way to copy all text in PSD file?

I work with PSD layouts with many separate text layers and they often contain only one word.

Comment: Is that a programming question ? Please have a look at [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: From one point it's "software tools commonly used by programmers". Because HTML/CSS/JS technologist uses it. From another point - if there is a simple way to programmatically get it - it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the 'type' layers from your layers pane, using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click (depending on whether you have a Mac or Windows machine), or, if they're adjacent, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, then use Photoshop's Edit > Copy to copy the layers.

Comment: Thanks for link. About answer - it does not work

Comment: Have you tried anything else yourself?